# Start Kafka connector using the source code

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to start the Kafka connector using the source code, but I always encounter some errors.

this is my configuration.I don't know if there's something wrong with the way I configured it.

[myconfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytLe3.png)

Here are some error messages.

```
[2023-09-12 17:04:22,050] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
[2023-09-12 17:04:24,566] INFO Reflections took 2369 ms to scan 85 urls, producing 7787 keys and 30651 values [using 8 cores] (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2023-09-12 17:04:24,584] WARN could not get type for name org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlListener from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlListener
    at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:312)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:382)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:140)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:298)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:241)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:78)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you've only shown a warning that can be ignored, not an error. You can turn off `org.reflections` logs in the log4j file.

Trying to use the source code directly will only cause problems

`connect-standalone.sh` calls `kafka-run-class.sh`, which in turn sets up the necessary CLASSPATH needed for the JVM to actually run the ConnectStandalone Java class.

Trying to run the code from an IDE will cause conflicts with the IDE's classpath.

Instead, you could setup a Shell Script or Docker action in IntelliJ run config, not a Java one, both would run the compiled code and not require you to download Kafka source repo.

Comment: Thx bro,I have already solved the problem. Originally, I wanted to debug this program, but I found out I could use IDEA for remote debugging, so I resolved it. Still, I want to thank you for being willing to answer my questions.